# Facebook Like Button - APP ID tag invalid

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Good afternoon.

I am having problems with my Facebook LIKE button.

When I click "like" I get an error:

The app ID "150674548325075" Specified Within the "fb: app_id" meta tag WAS invalid.

The link in my setup is this: http://www.tuimagenpersonal.com/minicurso/

I'm not using the APP ID 150674548325075 message says .. if you see the source code of my link you will see that I do not use this APP ID, but another.

Why give this error?

Thanks and best regards.

**Javier**

Comment: I don't see an app id in your source.

Comment: Don't think this will solve your problem, but you have an equal sign before the http:// in your data-href property: `data-href="=http://www.tuimagenpersonal.com/minicurso/index.php"`

Comment: @javier how did you fix this one?